# c++ An interesting result

Tags: c++

This code somehow always adds to the conclusion 12142.
For example insert 12; the output is 1212142, insert 1 + 2; get 312142

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Token
{
public:
    char kind;
    double value;
};

class Token_stream
{
public:
    Token get();
    void putback(Token t);
private:
    bool full{ false };
    Token buffer;
};

void Token_stream::putback(Token t)
{
    buffer = t;
    full = true;
}
Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full)
    {
        full = false;
        return buffer;
    }
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;

    switch (ch)
    {
    case ';':
    case 'q':
    case '(': case ')': case '+':
    case '-': case '*': case '/':
        return Token{ ch };
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {
        cin.putback(ch);
        double val;
        cin >> val;
        return Token{ '8',val };
    }
    default:
        throw runtime_error("dont true token");
        break;
    }
}
Token_stream ts;

double expres();
double prim()
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind)
    {
    case '(':
    {
        double d = expres();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ')')
        {
            throw runtime_error("))))");
        }
        return d;
    }
    case '8':
        return t.value;
    default:
        throw runtime_error("perm");
    }
}
double term()
{
    double left = prim();
    Token t = ts.get();
    while (true)
    {
        switch (t.kind)
        {
        case '*':
            left *= prim();
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        case '/':
        {
            double d = prim();
            if (d == 0)
            {
                throw runtime_error("/0");
            }
            left /= d;
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        }
        default:
            ts.putback(t);
            return left;
        }
    }
}
double expres()
{
    {
        double left = term();
        Token t = ts.get();
        while (true)
        {
            switch (t.kind)
            {
            case '+':
                left += term();
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            case '-':
                left -= term();
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            default:
                ts.putback(t);
                return left;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    double val = 0;
    while (cin)
    {
        Token t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind == 'q') break;
        if (t.kind == ';')
            cout << "=" << val << '/n';
        else
            ts.putback(t);
        val = expres();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is taken from the book Programming - Principles and Practice Using C ++

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Note that it can often be worth trying on multiple compilers. I don't know if MSVC is capable of giving warnings for this, but a quick test on Coliru gave me *warning: multi-character character constant*.

Comment: @chris - very nice!  The message points directly to the error - makes you wonder why other compilers (with their default settings) don't warn on that.  (Though, in this case I can imagine still looking at `'/n'` and _still_ not seeing it ... such is the power of expectations ...)

Comment: I find the ability to _read_ to be a useful skill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look here:

```
if (t.kind == ';')
   cout << "=" << val << '/n';
```

`'/n'` is the character `/` followed by the character `n`, squeezed into what's known as a "multi-character literal". These are actually `int`s with implementation-defined values; on your system, apparently that's the number 12142.

**You meant the single character `'\n'`.**

[image: How to draw a backslash]

*In future, locate and solve problems like this by constructing a [minimal testcase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In doing so, you would eventually have ended up with a test program that simply said `cout << '/n'` and output `12142`; at that point, if you still didn't spot the typo, you'd have a very simple thing to look up and/or ask about.*

Comment: Ok, @Lightness, did you construct that animated GIF specifically for this answer?  Or you had it squirrelled away just for answers of this sort?  Or ????   Impressive, in any case!

Comment: @davidbak: Special commission! Only takes 30s :) https://screentogif.codeplex.com/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint

Comment: thank you!  A shiny new toy!

Comment: @davidbak: It's really handy for demonstrating proposed GUI implementations/fixes as attachments on issue trackers

Comment: For anyone wondering *why* the value is 12142, the likely answer is that in the OP's implementation, `'/'` has the integral value 47, `'n'` has the integral value 110, and these are "concatenated" into an int a la `<byte1><byte2><47><110>` (leaving endianness out of the picture), giving a value of 47*2^8 + 110 = 12142.

Comment: Or for a one-of-a-kind custom "let me google that for you" demonstration when you want to easily send instructions to someone.  And other uses too.  A nice tool!  (One excellent feature of SO is you frequently learn new stuff, when reading answers, that aren't even related to the question!)

Comment: @chris -1 for trying to drag this comment thread back on track ... though you are, of course, correct.

Comment: @chris: Sounds right

Comment: @Андрей: Not entirely sure what you wanted `throw runtime_error("/0");` to do, either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Looks like it signifies division by 0.